# Write half address to structure at compiling/linking time

Tags: c, gcc, 16-bit

I wrote code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int vari;

#if 1
struct xx {
  uint16_t p_vari;
} st ={
  .p_vari=(uint16_t)(uintptr_t)&vari,
};
#else
struct xx {
  void *p_vari;
} st ={
  .p_vari=&vari,
};
#endif


int main(void) {

  return 0;
}
```

If I try to write first 16bit of address in to structure,
(first variant of code) I got:

```
  vari.c:9:3: error: initializer element is not constant
  vari.c:9:3: error: (near initialization for 'st.p_vari')
```

If I write the address on void*(second variant of code), gcc is compiled success.

How I can make first variant?

I need it, because gcc can't work with 16 bit addressing,
but I needed generate structure that include 16 bit address.
I want get result at linking or compilling time.

Comment: Maybe try a **union** with a `void*` and `uint16_t` field.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as 16-bit addressing in a 32-bit (or 64-bit program). Addresses always have the same size, which depends on the architecture.

The problem here is that the linker can only do specific address manipulations, not arbitrary computations.
When a variable holds a static address, the compiler marks it as such. Then the linker and loader know to update it according to the real address. But all they can do is put in an address - not take the address and manipulate it (e.g. throw away bits).

Comment: The C standard does not specify that different types of pointers have the same size, even within one program. A C implementation may have pointers of different sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, You're right, though it doesn't really affect the answer. In most 32bit architectures there's no such thing as a 16bit pointer.

Comment: The deliberate code in the question that extracts just 16 bits of an address suggests the OP has special needs regarding addressing. Therefore, making assumptions about the addressing on their target platform is premature.

Comment: Perhaps I can set this value at the linker script?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that globals are initialised by the compiler/linker.

The compiler understands when it has to initialise a `void *` with an address that is only known at link time, but it doesn't understand it when you try to do it at compile time as is the case with `uint16_t`. Try using a union:

```
union xx {
  uint16_t p_vari_16;
  void * p_vari_p;
} st ={
  .p_vari_p=&vari
};
```

But beware that this will only lead to correct results on little endian architectures. Use an initialiser in your `main` to have maximum portability.

Comment: Good variant. But if I initing p_vari_p, and next I write(on init too) to second half (&p_vari_16+1), I lose first half (p_vari_16).